# CollapsingToolBarLayout has dual toolbar

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am having issues with implementing `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. I have this problem:

Yes, I've got to place the view in the layout, but it collapses below the original toolbar (or ActionBar for that matter) as shown in the image below. I have no idea how to fix this. 
[image: The <code>CollapsingToolbarLayout</code> collapses under the <code>ActionBar</code>]

Thanks for any help. I am using **Android Studio 2.1.1**.

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ArticleActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/featuredImage"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:contentDescription="@string/article_image"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/article_container" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_share_variant" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Does your activity's theme extends any of the `NoActionBar` base themes?

Comment: @EricDS yes it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out where I went wrong. I had left out the theme statement in the manifest. All I had to do was add the line `android:theme="AppTheme.NoActionBar"` to my activity in the manifest.

However, this brought up two new issues:

1. The new ToolBar scrolls out of view (does not stick to the top.)
2. The **back button** that should lead me to my previous activity is gone. However, I'll ask this as a separate question if I do not get the solutions from researching.

Comment: I resolved the first issue by removing the line `app:layout_scrollFlags` from the `FrameLayout` which I changed into a `NestedScrollView`. However, issue #2 still persists.